# Writing an sql query for name of the youngest student(s) from the ‘Computer Science’ department along with the total marks obtained by him (them)."

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sum

I have been given a table of students data and I have to write query for the following:

*Retrieve the name of the youngest student(s) from the ‘Computer Science’ department
along with the total marks of all subjects obtained by him (them).*

The database schema are as follows:

```
depts(
deptcode char(3) primary key,
deptname char(70) not null);
```

```
students(
rollno number(2) primary key,
name varchar(50),
bdate date check(bdate < TO_DATE('2004-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
deptcode char(3) references depts(deptcode)
on delete cascade,
hostel number check(hostel<20),
parent_inc number(8,1));
```

```
crs_regd(
crs_rollno number(2) references students(rollno) on delete cascade,
on delete cascade,
marks number(5,2),
primary key(crs_rollno));
```

I wrote the query as

```
select s.name, s.bdate, sum(c.marks) as marks from students s
inner join crs_regd c
on s.rollno=c.crs_rollno
inner join (
select st.name, min(st.bdate) as bdate from students st, depts d
where st.deptcode=d.deptcode and d.deptname='Computer Science and Technology' group by st.name) x
on x.name=s.name and x.bdate=s.bdate group by s.name,s.bdate;
```

The obtained output is :

```
JOSH MARTIN                                14-JUN-99         274
GARY LEWIS                                 30-JUN-99         90
SUSANE SHAW                                26-JAN-99         185
```

(where each column represents the marks obtained in a different subject, all belong to `Computer Science' department)

Expected output

```
SUSANE SHAW                                26-JAN-99         185
```

Where am I making a mistake? If I am wrong please inform. If any other information required please drop a comment below.  If there is other way to write this query please discuss.

Comment: What's the expected result if GARY LEWIS has the same bdate as SUSANE SHAW?

Comment: @jarlh In that case both the records should be shown.

Comment: I think you need to **ORDER BY** bdate **ASC** and set **LIMIT** 1.

Comment: @FredrikStigsson, will only return 1 user even if there are several users with the same, latest bday. Switch to modern `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES` to get them all.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Focus your question on *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post if you are still stuck.

Comment: Your main goal is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group by` in the subquery is wrong.
**EDIT** : As I do agree with the `join` usage comment, I rewrote the query

```sql
SELECT s.name, s.bdate, SUM(c.marks) AS marks 
FROM students s
        INNER JOIN crs_regd c ON s.rollno=c.crs_rollno
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MIN(st.bdate) AS bdate
            FROM students st
                    INNER JOIN depts d ON st.deptcode=d.deptcode
            WHERE d.deptname='Computer Science and Technology'
        ) x ON x.bdate = s.bdate
GROUP BY s.name, s.bdate;
```

The subquery you wrote returns the min birth date for each student instead of the min birthdate for the whole department

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select s.name, s.bdate, sum(c.marks) as marks from students s
inner join crs_regd c on s.rollno=c.crs_rollno
where s.bdate in 
(select min(st.bdate) as bdate from students st inner join depts d
on st.deptcode=d.deptcode and d.deptname='Computer Science and Technology')
group by s.name, s.bdate;
```

Comment: The ```group by``` clause is missing here to achieve the ```sum(c.marks)```